# EOFException Java y dos errores mas

Tags: java

Os explico estoy haciendo un programa en java  que inserta un Id, apellido departamento y salario por argumentos. En un fichero .dat, pero primero comprueba que no exista alguna persona con el mismo id, finalmente lee todos los "empleados" y los muestra por consola. La desesperación es que me da tres errores que no soy capaz de solventar. Os pongo el código a continuación, me serviría de mucho el que es lo que hecho mal y como solventarlo.

```
public class Programa3 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        int input_id = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String input_apellido = args[1];
        int input_dep = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        Double input_salario = Double.parseDouble(args[3]);

        comprobarEmpleado(input_id,input_apellido,input_dep,input_salario);

        leer();

    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        System.out.println("Introduce bien los datos por argumentos/parametros");
    }

} //ok
public static void insertarEmpleado (int w_id, String w_apellido,int w_dep, Double w_salario ) throws IOException {
    File fichero = new File("src/AleatorioEmpleado.dat");
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(fichero, "rw");

    int posicion = (int) file.length();
    file.seek(posicion);
    file.writeInt(w_id);
    file.writeChars(w_apellido);
    file.writeInt(w_dep);
    file.writeDouble(w_salario);

    file.close();

}

public static void comprobarEmpleado(int c_id, String c_apellido,int c_dep, Double c_salario) throws IOException{
    File fichero = new File ("src/AleatorioEmpleado.dat");
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile (fichero, "r");

    int id ,posicion;
    posicion = 0;

    for ( ; ; ) {
        file.seek (posicion);
        id = file.readInt(); 


        if (id == c_id) {
            System.out.printf("El empleado ya existe");
            break;

        }else {
            posicion = posicion + 36;
            System.out.println(posicion + " " +file.length());
            if (posicion == file.length()+4) {
                if (c_id > 0) {
                    insertarEmpleado(c_id,c_apellido,c_dep,c_salario);
                }else {
                    System.out.println("El id introducido no es valido");
                }
                break; 
            }
        }

    }

    file.close();
}

public static void leer() throws IOException{
    File fichero = new File ("src/AleatorioEmpleado.dat");
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile (fichero, "r");
    int id, dep ,posicion;
    Double salario;
    char apellido[]= new char[10], aux;
    posicion =0;

    for ( ; ; ){
        // Nos posicionamos en posicion
        file.seek (posicion); 

        // Obtengo identificar de Empleado
        id = file.readInt(); 

        for ( int i =0; i<apellido.length; i++) {
            // Voy leyendo carÃ¡cter a carÃ¡cter el apellido y lo guardo
            aux = file.readChar(); 

            // en el array apellido
            apellido[i]=aux;
        }
        String apellidos = new String (apellido);

        //Lectura de departamento y salario
        dep = file.readInt();
        salario = file.readDouble();

        if (id >0)
            System.out.printf("ID: %s, Apellido: %s, Departamento: %d, Salario: %.2f %n", id,
            apellidos.trim(), dep, salario);

        //Me posiciono para el siguiente empleado.
        //Cada uno ocupa 36 bytes
        posicion = posicion + 36; 

        //Si he recorrido todo el fichero saldo del for
        if (file.getFilePointer() == file.length()) break;
    }
    file.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia es separar mejor el código para hacer las operaciones que necesitas.
Para extraer un archivo de texto plano podrías usar este algoritmo

```
public Stream<String> leerAchivoExterno(String rutaArchivo) {
    Stream<String> lineas = null;

    try {
        lineas = Files.lines(Paths.get(rutaArchivo), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ArchivoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return lineas;
}
```

Ya recuperado la información del .dat, puedes almacenar la información en una clase con los atributos coincidentes a los datos que siempre vas a necesitar.

```
public class Empleado {

private int id;
String apellido;
String departamento;
double salario;

public Empleado() {
}

public Empleado(int id, String apellido, String departamento, double salario) {
    this.id = id;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.departamento = departamento;
    this.salario = salario;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public String getDepartamento() {
    return departamento;
}

public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {
    this.departamento = departamento;
}

public double getSalario() {
    return salario;
}

public void setSalario(double salario) {
    this.salario = salario;
}

}
```

Posteriormente, para escribir toda la información de interés puedes usar este algoritmo.

```
public void escribirArchivo(Path rutaDestino, List<String> lineas) {

    try {
         if(Files.exists(rutaDestino)){ // escribe al final
                Files.write(rutaDestino, lineas, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
         }else{ // escribe todo el archivo
               Files.write(rutaDestino, lineas, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
         }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ArchivoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

En lineas generales necesitaras al menos estas operaciones y todas aquellas que necesites agregar. Pero acostumbrate a usar una clase como entidad para recuperar o mapear estructura de información de cualquier sistema que parezca una base de datos.